# How convert BLOB string to human readable format string in java

Tags: java

I have a frame work which executes db query and gets data and assigns data to a variable in this processes the frame work is converting blob data to string which is in un redable format. Actually the BLOB data is an xml but the framework is some how making it a string the stringis something like this

```
PEhlYWRlcj48TVFNRD48U291cmNlUXVldWU+V1cuRVNCLkVOVFJZLlNFUlZJQ0UuSU48L1NvdXJjZVF1ZXVlPjxUcmFuc2FjdGlvbmFsPnRydWU8L1RyYW5zYWN0aW9uYWw+PEVuY29kaW5n
```

how can i convert this to readable format

Comment: Your string is Base64-encoded XML. Use a Base64 decoder to decode it. For example try copy&pasting the string above here: https://www.base64decode.org/

Comment: Thank you so much how can we identify that the string was in bse64-encoded data

Comment: It was just a guess, it looked like Base64 data to me and that turned out to be correct.